# What does P0328 means?

Tags: toyota, obd-ii, yaris, lpg, knock-sensor

`Knock sensor High Input`

The problem reappears even by clearing the error with the knock sensor unplugged… Is it something expected ?

Does it necessarily mean there’s a short circuit ? If not what does it mean ?

Comment: Just clearing the error will not correct it. You need to check what signals are there and if they are within the limits they should be.

Comment: @SolarMike I dont know how to check knock sensor signals from obd.